# MariaDB will not start on reboot after changing data directory

Tags: centos, mysql, vagrant, mariadb

I'm running a local vagrant setup with Centos 7. I recently changed the data directory to persist data across destroys of the box. However, now MariaDB will not start on reboot. My setup is as follows.

`.cnf` file in `/etc/my.cnf.d` (definitely being loaded)

1. Install MariaDB via yum
2. `systemctl enable mariadb.service`
3. `systemctl start mariadb.service`

So on initial `vagrant up` the service starts and is contactable with correct data. However, after a `vagrant halt`, all subsequent boots do not start the service automatically.

Any ideas will be much appreciated. Assuming it's something stupid but been banging my head against it a little too long now.

Comment: So don't change the data directory. There's no real good reason to do so anyway.

Comment: Well for my requirements there are, and it's something that should be able to be done.

Comment: Why do you think you need to change the data directory?

Comment: I don't think I need to, it's a solution to persistence and a time saver, something that should be able to be achieved.

Comment: Hello philipobenito, are sure the data directory is available at boot time? Not that mariaDB is trying to start before the directory has been mounted.

Comment: @EamonnTravers interesting, could well be this as a manual start after boot works fine, I'll have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

The source of your problem has a name: selinux

For a quick and very dirty solution, "setenforce 0" as root. To make this change permanent, you have to edit "/etc/sysconfig/selinux" and change from "enforcing" to "permissive", or (copying from the on line manual):

On the System menu, point to Administration and then click Security Level and Firewall to display the Security Level Configuration dialog box.

1. Click the SELinux tab.
2. In the SELinux Setting select either Disabled, Enforcing or Permissive, and then click OK.
3. If you changed from Enabled to Disabled or vice versa, you need to restart the machine for the change to take effect.

For a by-the-book solution, you have to create a new selinux policy, which can be a daunting task by itself. If you have some time at hand and are curious enough, try it.

Comment: Or set the correct file context on the other directory, or best of all, don't change the directory to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelHampton at this point you're just not being helpful, changing the data directory may not be the best idea, it's a quick and dirty solution for my specific needs, but at no point have you explained why it's a bad idea or why I shouldn't be doing it. As for file context, if that's a helpful answer then please provide it. Otherwise, what are the point of your comments other than what comes across as elitism?

Comment: @philipobenito While I agree that Michael is probably hammering his point a bit too much without elaborating. I think at this point you'll notice that it is not at all a quick solution, only dirty. Especially considering the actual [intended use of SELinux permissive mode](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing).

Comment: @philipobenito Why? I decline to answer because you gave me a bad attitude. That's all.

Comment: @gmelis I'm actually already set as permissive

Comment: @Reaces that isn't directly related to the change of data directory though is it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton if that's what you perceived as bad attitude then fine, quite easy to just navigate away from the page rather than being purposely unhelpful.

Comment: @philipobenito It's related to the answer above. The answer above suggests changing your SELinux from `enforcing` to `permissive`. Which is what the link in my comment talks about. I'm personally of the opinion that for a box that hosts a database, you should never use destroy, only halts. But that might be my bias as a database administrator speaking.

Comment: @Reaces my issue is that I'm limited on provisioning options for this specific environment so changes need a destroy. I'm mirroring a horrible legacy setup (it's not just a DB box) and looking for the fastest way to handle being able to make these changes across a team so changing the data directory seemed like a perfect solution. The answer above I don't think addresses my issue to be honest.